# jquery + populate selectbox with numbers

Tags: jquery

i want to populate selectbox dynamically with the count available from total number of text boxes,

i.e.

if i have text 2 textboxes then the selectbox should like

> ```
> <select>      
> <option value="1">1</option>      
> <option value="2">2</option> 
> </select>
> ```

and when i add a new textbox dynamically i.e third textbox then the one more option should be added dynamically, like..

```
<select>        
<option value="1">1</option>        
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option> 
</select>
```

please guide me with possible approach for this

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check-it Out:**

**JQUERY:**

```
   $("#aAdd").click(function(){
    var vText = $("input:text").length+1;
    $("<br/><input type='text' value="+ vText +"></input>").appendTo("#divAppend");
    $("#selOption").append("<option value="+ vText +">"+ vText +"</option>");
    return false;
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divAppend">
</div>
<br />
<select id="selOption" style="width:100px;">   
    <option value="0">[Select]</option>
</select>
<br />
<a id="aAdd" href="#">Add</a>
```

**[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ilidu5)**

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var textBoxes = $('input[type="text"]');

textBoxes.each(function() { 
    var nextNo = textBoxes.length;
    $('select').append('<option value="' +nextNo + '">' + nextNo + '</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

#### HTML

```
<input type="button" value="add">
<select id="mySelect">      
<option value="1">1</option>      
<option value="2">2</option> 
</select>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('input[type="button"]').live('click',function() {

    var last = $('select option:last').val();
    var oneMore = parseInt(last)+1;
     $('#mySelect').
          append($("<option></option>").
          attr("value",oneMore).
          text(oneMore)); 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CK4fH/1/)**